# Use different settings for a Views' block basing on the content type of the node being shown

Tags: views, nodes

I have 2 content types,  photo articles and video articles. On a photo article page, I want to have a block that shows 5 other photo articles. When I place this same block on a video page, it should show 5 video articles.

How can I use contextual filters to achieve this? I don't want to install a separate module to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Entity Views Attachment](http://drupal.org/project/eva) to attach your view to those content types instead of using blocks. EVA will allow you to pass in the content type of the current article as a contextual filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid creating 2 views (for whatever reason), you can create 1 view with a Contextual Filter for Node:Type. But you'll need [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and [cTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools).

With this, you get a new display for Views called "Content pane": Output your View in this display, and you can select these Panes from "Mini Panels" module that comes with "Panels" module. Mini Panels creates blocks for you; you just need to create 2 instances of the mini pane, with a different contextual filter applied to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup 2 different views: one for related photos, and one for related videos. Create a block display for both. You use a regular filter to only show photos in the photo view and only videos in the video view. Limit it to 5 items.

You want a contextual filter for "content:nid" to prevent the current photo from showing in your view. 
When the filter value is not in the URL, use "content ID from URL" for "Provide default value"; then click "more" and select "Exclude" to exclude.

Now you just need to show your photo block on your photo page and vise versa. Go to "Structure >> Blocks", assign the photo block to a region, and restrict it to your photo pages or your type photo.

Comment: That's what I eventually ended up doing. My question was could I actually avoid creating 2 views and somehow have 1 view adapt based on which page it was being displayed on.